# how to stop python program when time.sleep() is in progressing

Tags: python, time, bots, sleep

i made a bot that control my mouse and my keyboard to make the games im playing easier but somehow i can't stop that program easily... **i made a loop with condition when i press enter the program will be stopped but the time.sleep() progressing dnt allow that happening**, however i can't make an integer condition because **i want my program unstoppable i mean it must stop when i press a key on my keyboard**
*for example*:

```
import keyboard
import time

while True:
    print('hello world')
    time.sleep(3)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        break
```

**i know that i can hold 'enter' button for 3 secs but my real program has time.sleep() duration bigger than 1 min that i can't hold enter all that time**,
*is there any other code like time.sleep() i can use to solve my problem ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a 3-second sleep how about 30 short 0.1-second naps? Food for  thought.

```
import keyboard
import time

enter_pressed = 0
while True:
    print('hello world')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
        enter_pressed += 1
    else:
        enter_pressed = 0

    if enter_pressed >= 10:
        break # enter pressed for 1 sec
```

Comment: Why do they even have to sleep at that point

Comment: It is for granularity and fine control

Comment: my real program duration have more than time.sleep(60) that i can't hold 'enter' to close 
the program

Comment: thank you bro i got a good idea with this ^^